# User Reputation League link is missing

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design

The link on user profile page to the [User Reputation League for Drupal Answers](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/99/alltime/drupal/2008-07-31?sort=reputationchange) (ie, the  **top x% this month** link) is missing.

This link does appear on profiles on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a [thread on Meta.SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153042/user-league-information-missing-in-the-profile-page) by [Nick Craver](http://stackexchange.com/users/7598/nick-craver)

> This is intentional for the moment, we have an issue with the leagues
>   population causing an inordinate amount of load on our SQL servers
>   which I have yet to find time to investigate.
>
> I just turned it on for Stack Overflow specifically, it's the SE 2.0
>   sites causing the SQL issue...Stack Overflow is fine.