# Are the "user reputation league" and "user accept rate" coming back?

Tags: support, design

I found out reading [this question](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2173/6461), that the "Reputation League" is taken down due to performance issues.
Lately, I've also noticed that the "Accept Rate" (which used to show below every user name asking a question) is also missing.
These were good features. I personally liked the later more than the former. Is the site planning to have them back? Or are they permanently removed?

Comment: I wish the accept rate would come back too!  I wish there were intuitive ways newer users could figure out the concepts of accepting an answer and such (without being prompted, which seems too heavy-handed), and that was an obvious cue!!!

Comment: @Boriana Fair point! I too think by removing this feature, new users can choose not to accept the answer, because some of them might not know the significance. And it was also encouraging for other users as they were able to make out what type of user (OP) they are dealing with.

Answer (score 2):

As shown in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164654/140449) to [Let's stop displaying a user's accept rate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136951/lets-stop-displaying-a-users-accept-rate), the accept rate has been removed, and it is not going to be shown again. Jeff Atwood, one of the founders of Stack Exchange proposed an alternative in [Replace accept rate with citizenship level](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165179/replace-accept-rate-with-citizenship-level), for which Shog9's answer says:

> While I like the idea of a general-purpose "citizenship" metric in theory, watering it down with stuff like flagging just makes it harder to interpret. The best idea we could come up with ended up being sort of a parallel reputation system that increased whenever you did *something* positive on the site - while interesting, I'm not convinced this would do much to encourage *specific* forms interaction the way accept rate did.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the same link which @[MPD](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/users/835/mpd) added some time ago.

The reputation league for Drupal StackExchange still exists : http://stackexchange.com/leagues/99/alltime/drupal. It is taken down from the user profile probably because of performance issues.